# Задание элементу нового CSS значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо создать картинку 300px на 300px, добавить возможность приближать и отдалять с помощью клавиш "+" и "-".

Не могу задать новое CSS значение элементу после условия `if`. К примеру, простой `alert` также не выводится.

```
$(document.body).append('<div class="div1" style="position:relative;border:5px solid black; width:300px; height:300px;"</div>');
$('.div1').append('<img id="img1" src="images/10.jpg" style="position: absolute; margin: auto;top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 300px; height: 300px;"/>');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        a = $('img').height(); //height
        b = $('img').width(); //width

        c = parseInt(a) + 10; //width plus one step Intvalue
        d = parseInt(b) + 10; //height plus one step Intvalue

        e = parseInt(a) - 10; //width minus one step Intvalue
        f = parseInt(b) - 10; //height minus one step Intvalue

        if (event.keyCode == 107) {
            $('img').css('width', d + 'px') //change css Intvalue + "px"
            $('img').css('height', c + 'px') //change css Intvalue + "px"
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 109) {
            $('img').css('height', e + 'px')//change css Intvalue + "px"
            $('img').css('width', c + 'px')//change css Intvalue + "px"
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коды клавиш "+" и "-" равны 43 и 45 соответственно, даже если вместо нормализованного `event.which` использовать `event.keyCode`.

Также код был несколько упрощён и улучшен. Например, нет смысла использовать `parseInt()` для обработки ширины и высоты изображения, так как `.width()` и `.height()` и так возвращают `Number`. А вот закэшировать `$('img')` в переменной смысл имеет, чтобы избавиться от необходимости искать элемент в документе много раз. `$('body').append()` было перенесено внутрь `document.ready`, чтобы скрипт можно было размещать и в `<head>`.

Код целиком:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('body').append('<div class="div1" style="position:relative;border:5px solid black; width:300px; height:300px;"</div>');
    $('.div1').append('<img id="img1" src="images/10.jpg" style="position: absolute; margin: auto;top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 300px; height: 300px;"/>');

    $(document).on("keypress", function(event)
    {
        var image = $('img');
        var imageWidth = image.width();
        var imageHeight = image.height();
        if (event.which == 43 || event.which == 45)
        {
            var sizeChange = (event.which == 43) ? 10 : -10;
            image.css('width', (imageWidth + sizeChange) + "px");
            image.css('height', (imageHeight + sizeChange) + "px");
        }
    });
});
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5asnagk/).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы помогли!

Comment: @Dmitriy, так отметьте как решенный, это лучше чем просто "спасибо", которое нарушает правила.

Comment: ок, я поставил зеленую галочку под Вашим ответов, этого достаточно или еще что-то нужно сделать, я здесь в 1 раз

Comment: @Dmitriy нет, этого достаточно :)

Comment: хахаха)), извините, не так прочитал, галочку поставил)