# Изменение CSS свойств scale и zoom у элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Как задать шаг изменения CSS свойств `scale` и `zoom` у элемента `$('img')`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        a = $('img').height(); //height
        b = $('img').width(); //width

        c = parseInt(a) + 10; //width plus one step Intvalue
        d = parseInt(b) + 10; //height plus one step Intvalue

        e = parseInt(a) - 10; //width minus one step Intvalue
        f = parseInt(b) - 10; //height minus one step Intvalue

        if (event.keyCode == 107) {   //scale или zoom вместо width и height 

            $('img').css('width', d + 'px') //change css Intvalue + "px" 
            $('img').css('height', c + 'px') //change css Intvalue + "px"
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 109) {   //scale или zoom вместо width и height 

            $('img').css('height', e + 'px')//change css Intvalue + "px"
            $('img').css('width', c + 'px')//change css Intvalue + "px"
        }
    })
```

Comment: Извините, поправлю себя, свойство css, скрипт Jquery, мне нужно задать шаг,                if (event.keyCode == 43) {
                          image.css('width', d + 'px') //change css Intvalue + "px"
                          image.css('height', c + 'px')

Comment: только нужна не широта, и высота(картинка начинает вылазить) а так же задать шаг scale и зум, грубо говоря                                               scale + step = newscale и zoom + step = Newzoom                                             не знаю, как правильно оформить

Comment: и лучше бы знать, как находить информацию самому

Comment: Документация по jQuery находится [тут](https://api.jquery.com). Оформляется вопрос так: описывается, что сделано, что должно было получиться и  в чём именно возникла проблема. Вдобавок в вопрос помещается краткий достоверный код, необходимый для повторения проблемы (в данном случае JS + HTML). После этого вполне можно рассчитывать на быстрый и правильный ответ :)

Comment: понял) в принципе вопросе прост, шаг свойству width можно задать     b = image.width(); - ширина; d = b + 10 - шаг новому свойству width;            image.css('width', d + 'px')  -  а здесь мы говорим, что у ширины новое свойство, и с каждым нажатием она будет меняться на 10, как такое же проделать с zoom или scale

Comment: просто перед этим ошибка была именно в номере ключа я его изменил с 107 и 109 на 43 и 45 и все заработало, а так все код был рабочий, и функции запустились, но картинка, при уменьшении и расширении стала вылазить за края, поэтому я внести правки, и использовать свойство zoom или scale

Comment: Но я всё же работал со своим кодом: он и короче, и переменным даны осмысленные имена, и `$('img')` в переменной хранится. В общем, изменение CSS свойств `zoom` и `translate: scale()` продемонстрированы в [этом версии](http://jsfiddle.net/h5asnagk/1/). Если это вообще то, что нужно, то оформлю это ответом.

Comment: потрясающе, но ничего не понятно))) хотелось бы в первую очередь, круто выглядит, где вы этому учились?

Comment: (event.which == 43) ? 0.1 : -0.1; можно узнать что означает эта строчка?

Comment: В примере `zoom`, равно как и `scale` по обеим осям, изменяются на 0.1 за шаг. Это вообще то, что требуется? Возможно, одно должно уменьшаться, а другое - увеличиваться? Я изучал документацию по jQuery, разбирался в основах (и не только в них) JS, писал с проекты с использованием JS и jQuery, отвечал примерно год на вопросы по JS и jQuery на http://stackoverflow.com. Вот и вся история.

Comment: в конечном итоге получилось то, что нужно, это ваш код, я просто хотел понять как это сделать. Грубо говоря, одно дело списать, другое понять. Вам наверное проще сделать новый код ) а так в принципе все верно..

Comment: мне хотелось просто отредактировать свой, изменить пару строчек и все

Comment: image.css('zoom', imageZoom + zoomChange);  хотел задать intvalue zoomChange только другим путем, более быстрым и простым)

Comment: и это все есть в документации? я просто совсем недавно начал этим заниматься, html css, а js и вообще как неделя

Comment: С `transform` всё не так просто: пришлось искать на SO как выдернуть `scaleX` и `scaleY` из значения. Поэтому всё это дело с `matrixRegex` проще не сделать. В конечном итоге, я ведь не менял логику работы программы. Только переименовал переменные и кое-где укоротил код.

Comment: Да нет, все верно, но хочется понятней, с матрицами я вообще никогда не встречался, я хотел узнать  
image.css('zoom', imageZoom + zoomChange); можно ли получить и подставить это значение переменной ZoomChange другим путем?

Comment: Код, несколько больше похожий на первоначальный: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5asnagk/2/). Нужно понимать, что `zoom` не стоит менять на `10` за шаг: между `zoom` 1.0 и 11.0 огромная разница.

Comment: Там не матрица, а регулярное выражение. И нужно оно для того, чтобы из строки `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)` (которая лежит в `imageTransform`) выдернуть `1` и `1` (которые являются `scaleX` и `scaleY`).

Comment: согласен zoom выйдет большой, это можно поправить. да я помню тот код, спасибо, но вы мне подсказали по keycode, я просто поменял 4 числа и заработало, а копипастить код как-то не хочется

Comment: можно ли допустим сделать                                                                    var imageZoom = parseFloat(image.css('zoom'));                     
var ChangeZoom = var imageZoom + 0.5;
image.css('zoom', imageZoom + zoomChange);
???

Comment: Однако стараться сделать код лучше - идея, по-моему, хорошая. Если сравнить изначальную версию и мою (в которых, опять-таки подчеркну, логика работы одинаковая), то можно почерпнуть для себя несколько полезных вещей на будущее. Достаточно лишь разобраться в коде. В `var ChangeZoom = var imageZoom + 0.5;` я вижу две проблемы: во-первых, должно быть не `var imageZoom`, а `imageZoom` (переменная была объявлена ранее), во-вторых, тогда переменная уже должна называться не `changeZoom`, a `newZoom`, потому что в ней хранится не "насколько изменить зум", а "новое значение зума".

Comment: да согласен, в исходнике убрал var, консоль ругалась, ну newZoom, да, так назвать логичнее, но не принципиально.
Опять же спасибо, вы подкинули идею по ParseInt, голова уже не варит. Спасибо, что заморочились), обязательно сохраню ваш исходник, позже почитаю подробнее
Еще вопросик, где поставить галочку, чтобы завершить вопрос?

Comment: На самом деле, названия переменных - очень важная вещь. Если правильно называть переменные, функции и не писать витиеватый код, то и комментарии в коде вообще будут не нужны. Вопрос можно просто удалить (должна быть кнопка-строка под телом и метками вопроса). Либо, опять же, я могу разместить ответ. если в этом есть смысл.

Comment: размести, хоть галочку поставлю тебе
ты просто супер герой )

Comment: В принципе, если достаточно времени потратить на изучение JS и jQuery, то это всё не будет казаться сложным. :) Я старался писать код максимально простым (не считая заимствованного рег. выражения). Кстати, имея 15+ репутации, за ответы можно ещё ставить `+1`, но это исключительно по желанию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идея реализация весьма схожа с [предыдущим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429871/). Отличиями являются наличие `parseFloat()` (потому что `.css('свойство')` возвращает `String`) и использование регулярного выражения (взятого из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603615/get-the-scale-value-of-an-element)) для получения значений `scale` из `transform`.

HTML:

```
<div class="div1" style="position:relative;border:5px solid black; width:300px; height:300px;">
    <img id="img1" src="images/10.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#img1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    zoom: 100%;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(document).on("keypress", function(event)
    {
        var image = $('img');
        var imageZoom = parseFloat(image.css('zoom'));
        var imageTransform = image.css('transform');
        var matrixRegex = /matrix\((-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0,\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0\)/,
            matches = imageTransform.match(matrixRegex);
        var scaleX = parseFloat(matches[1]);
        var scaleY = parseFloat(matches[2]);
        if (event.which == 43 || event.which == 45)
        {
            var zoomChange = (event.which == 43) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
            var scaleChange = (event.which == 43) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
            image.css('zoom', imageZoom + zoomChange);
            image.css('transform', 'scale(' + (scaleX + scaleChange) + ',' + (scaleY + scaleChange) + ')');
        }
    });
});
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5asnagk/1/).